# Can‘t Lock Android MTK 8050 CPU frequency

Tags: android, linux, performance, cpu, frequency

**Recently, I've been trying to lock the CPU core frequency for performance testing on MTK 8050. However, after modifying the CPU frequency, the value remains unchanged. The phone already has root access.Here are some details**

```bash
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # ls -l
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 affected_cpus
-r-------- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 cpuinfo_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:45 cpuinfo_max_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:45 cpuinfo_min_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 cpuinfo_transition_latency
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 related_cpus
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 scaling_available_frequencies
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 scaling_available_governors
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:45 scaling_cur_freq
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:49 scaling_driver
-rw-rw---- 1 system system 4096 2023-09-21 12:02 scaling_governor
-rw-rw-r-- 1 system system 4096 2023-09-20 21:15 scaling_max_freq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 system system 4096 2023-09-21 12:24 scaling_min_freq
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   4096 2023-09-21 12:51 scaling_setspeed
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 2023-09-21 12:45 stats
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # whoami
root
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # cat scaling_governor
userspace
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # cat scaling_available_frequencies
2600000 2507000 2354000 2200000 1985000 1855000 1740000 1624000 1537000 1451000 1335000 1162000 1046000 902000 700000 437000
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # echo 2600000 > scaling_setspeed
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 # cat scaling_setspeed
700000
TECNO-CK9n:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4 #
```

Comment: is mpdecision running?

Comment: stop mpdecision 
Unable to stop service 'mpdecision'
See dmesg for error reason.
# dmesg | grep mpdecision
[  493.106275] .(4)[1:init]init 21: [493032][9330]Control message: Could not find 'mpdecision' for ctl.stop from pid: 9638 (stop mpdecision)

Comment: It seems that MTK CPUs do not have "mpdecision."

Answer (score 1):

change `/proc/ppm/policy/ut_fix_freq_idx`

Works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).